# Wikidata get property of property

Tags: wikidata, sparql, ontology

This question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42171770/how-to-retrieve-the-hugo-winners-from-wikidata).

We have [the following query](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FAuthorLabel%20%3Fyear%20WHERE%20%7B%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP166%20wd%3AQ255032.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP50%20%3FAuthor%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP577%20%3Fyear%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D%20):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?AuthorLabel ?year WHERE {  
  ?item wdt:P166 wd:Q255032.
  ?item wdt:P50 ?Author .  
  ?item wdt:P577 ?year .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }    
}
```

We get items and these properties, for example Author, date of publication.

But we need to get not direct property, for example date of Award.

Item has **award received** property and this property has **point in time** property.

How can we get its value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `point in time` property of the award received is what Wikidata calls a [qualifier](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Help:Qualifiers):

> Along with sources and ranks, **qualifiers** allow statements to be expanded on, annotated, or contextualized beyond what can be expressed in just a simple property-value pair.

Here is the [modified query to access the point in time of the award received](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FauthorLabel%20%3FpublicationDate%20%3FdateOfAwardReceived%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP50%20%3Fauthor%20.%20%20%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP577%20%3FpublicationDate%20.%0A%20%20%3Fitem%20p%3AP166%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20ps%3AP166%20wd%3AQ255032%20.%0A%20%20%3FawardReceivedStatement%20pq%3AP585%20%3FdateOfAwardReceived%20.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%20%20%20%20%0A%7D):

```
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel ?authorLabel ?publicationDate ?dateOfAwardReceived WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P50 ?author .  
  ?item wdt:P577 ?publicationDate .
  ?item p:P166 ?awardReceivedStatement .
  ?awardReceivedStatement ps:P166 wd:Q255032 .
  ?awardReceivedStatement pq:P585 ?dateOfAwardReceived .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }    
}
```

Wikidata also has a short description and some examples about [how to work with qualifiers](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Working_with_qualifiers).

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to access **qualifiers**, that is statements on statements, all the doc you need is here: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/queries#Working_with_qualifiers